# Are there drawbacks to connecting a remote diode temperature sensor through a connector and cable interface?

Tags: diodes, cables, fan, controller, remote

I would like to connect an external temperature sensor (external to the PCB) to a the DP/DN pins of an EMC2103 fan controller. My plan would be to use a twisted pair cable with a generic TO-92 remote diode like 2N3904.

1. Are there any drawbacks of using a cable of an approximative length of 24"?
2. If it is feasible, are there any off-the-shelf remote diode sensor + cable I could buy?
3. It is not stated in the datasheet but could the DP/DN input work with a thermistors as these cable sensors are more common off-the-shelf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main drawback is noise picked up by the long cable run; the signal isn't very strong.  [App Note 10.14](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/000001839A.pdf) gives a very detailed treatment of ways to reduce the amount of noise picked up.  In your case, you will want to not only use twisted pair cable, but also *shielded* cable with the shield terminated at the board end only to prevent creating a ground loop.

Specific product recommendations for pre-wired transistors are off topic here but soldering a 2N3904 onto a cable only takes a minute (I looked around briefly but couldn't find any anyways).  Remember to sleeve each joint.

The temperature measurement will not work with a thermistor as the interpretation of the received signal is different.